Does an Emanation extend from the center or the edge of its creature/object of origin?
In the 2024 rules, the Emanation has been added as an Area of Effect. From the Rules Glossary:

An Emanation is an area of effect that extends in straight lines from a creature or an object in all directions. The effect that creates an Emanation specifies the distance it extends.

This further links to the entry for an Area of Effect, which says (among other things):

An area of effect has a point of origin, a location from which the effect’s energy erupts. The rules for each shape specify how to position its point of origin.

My confusion arises because areas of effect are stated to all have a point as their origin, but then the Emanation uses a creature or object as its origin. Maybe it's a case of specific vs. general, but nonetheless, it leads to ambiguity: is the Emanation measured from the edge of the creature/object (like reach is) or from its center (like a spherical area of effect)?
For example, if a Large creature (~10-foot diameter) is the origin of a 10-foot Emanation, will the Emanation be 20-feet in diameter (extending 10 feet from the creature's center) or 30-feet in diameter (extending 10 feet from the creature's edge)?

I'm now leaning more toward concluding that an Emanation is NOT intended to begin at the center of the creature. If it did begin there, it would essentially be the same as a Sphere, in which case there seems little reason to create an entirely new AOE shape for it.

Related (from 2014 rules): If a paladin becomes Large, at what point does the paladin's aura originate?

Related (from 2014 rules): Does the radius of the Spirit Guardians spell depend on the size of the caster?, How large is a Globe of Invulnerability cast by a Large creature?, How big is the area of effect for the Ice Knife spell's explosion, when the spell targets a Large creature?

An Emanation extends from the edge of its origin
In general, AoE spells have a point of origin, which are specified per shape.

An area of effect has a point of origin, a location from which the effect’s energy erupts. The rules for each shape specify how to position its point of origin.

Specifically, Emanations are an AoE shape that originates from a creature or object.

An Emanation is an area of effect that extends in straight lines from a creature or an object in all directions.

Emanations are a specific kind of AoE shape, so specific beats general in this case. The "location", i.e. "point of origin", for emanations is not literally a geometrical point; rather, it is an object or creature.
For determining the range on a grid, the PHB suggests

Ranges. To determine the range on a grid between two things ... count squares from a square adjacent to one of them and stop counting in the space of the other one. Count by the shortest route.

under Movement and Position. This is conceptually equivalent to an emanation extending from the edge of a cell on a grid.

It might be useful to add discussion how to handle this on a grid then, where AoEs are always full squares (or hexes), once the new DMG comes out.

Some examples would help clarify whether a 10' emanation is 10' from the centre of the creature/object or 10' from the boundary of the creature/object and, when using a grid, how it is rounded to the fit the squares. (And if it makes a difference emanating from an Ogre or a Gelatinous Cube, both of which are large creatures but the Ogre can be approximated by a rounder shape whereas the gelatinous cube would entirely fill its grid squares).

You state edge of its origin but nothing you quote actually says that. Please clarify where this is coming from.

That's the English meaning of "from" in "...from a creature or an object in all directions". Without further specification, e.g. "From the center of mass of a creature or object...", there is no way to determine a more specific point.

@nonymous Fair enough, then what is the edge? Without a grid reference, this would depend on the size, anatomy and location of creature, right? Fully, I completely agree with how you rule, but I don't find it convincing that this actually exists in the rules.

@Wyrmwood, understood. Ya, you might consider flipping it on its head. It actually exists in the rules, but just appears ambiguous to someone who examines it too closely.

Your question is not answered in the rules.
Emanation [Area of Effect]

An Emanation is an area of effect that extends in straight lines from a creature or an object in all directions. The effect that creates an Emanation specifies the distance it extends.

emphasis mine

An Emanation moves with the creature or object that is its origin unless it is an instantaneous or a stationary effect.


An Emanation’s origin (creature or object) isn’t included in the area of effect unless its creator decides otherwise.

That's all we get so a plain reading would be, it depends on the size, anatomy and location of the creature. Software map aids generally support both options;  starting counting from 2.5 (center of 5' square) or 5 (edge of square). Thus a 5' emanation would either extend 2.5 ft away from the origin square (for a total of 7.5 ft from the center of the origin square, reaching 2.5 feet into adjacent squares, which is awkward), or 5' away from the origin, encompassing all adjacent squares.
RAI?
This is however, I suspect not rules as intended. RAI is most likely an emanation extends from the borders of the source's square, but it isn't what the rules say.
This ambiguity was introduced in 5th edition (2014) and continued in 2024. The rules don't want to specify the grid, since that's ostensibly an optional rule, but it leaves a high degree of confusion. Perhaps we'll get a better answer once the optional grid rules are provided in the 2024 DMG.
2014
Please note, with Xanathar's, the 2014 rules provided the following

If an area of effect is circular and covers at least half a square, it affects that square.

With that assumption, there's no difference between a 5' (self) from the center of the caster's square, and a 5' (self) from the edge of the caster's square.
This doesn't appear to have made it into 2024's emanation rules, however.
Update (post DMG 2024 release)
The 2024 Dungeon Master's Guide (DMG) does not provide additional clarifications regarding emanation rules beyond what is presented in the PHB. Good luck!

I'm sorry but I can't make sense of your 5'-emanation example. Please clarify. (I would understand an overall 5' radius or 7.5' radius, but where is the 2.5' coming from?)

@gto - If you count from the center of the square the caster (or source) is in, there is 2.5 ft to the edge of the square (at least in cardinal directions). It's the same as how you would get to 7.5 to reach adjacent squares. Since you understand that, perhaps how you understand the 2.5?

The 2024 DMG, not the 2025 version, is already available. The information provided on this topic is essentially the same as in the 2014 DMG

@Tarod "already" is a point in time. At the time of posting (2024-10-21), the 2024 DMG was not out yet. Thanks for the reminder to update this post after the release!

Oh, I'm so sorry :( I didn't notice the answer date. My apologies!

No worries good reminder!

The note about how the Xanathar's rule is the same either way doesn't account for diagonals, which are generally awkward when trying to convert feet to squares. A 5' emanation from the middle of the origin square doesn't cover half of the area of the diagonally neighboring square, and probably doesn't even reach the center of those squares, but if it's 5' from the edges of the origin square it definitely covers them. I think that maps better onto a gridless scenario of being surrounded on all sides by 8 people. I think it also makes the 'math' easier for everyone.

@aherocalledFrog - diagonals is a complicated topic, due to three available "variants" and no clear "standard". The DM is going to need to sort out whether he's using the standard (which includes Euclidean geometry in the descriptions), the PH Variant: Playing on a Grid (which treats circles as squares), or Xanathar's Areas of Effect on a Grid, which also assume "blocky" Euclidean.  Like I said, "good luck"!
